# Simple: maybe uses Vlookup

Tags: vlookup

I have a table with these columns: **Company**, **Person**, **Months Since Last Contacted**.

Now I want a table with all COMPANIES where no Person was contacted in the last 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but not with VLOOKUP, which returns a single value.  When you are looking for a subset of records, a filter is a common tool.  If you need to aggregate data, a pivot table is a common tool.

Not all spreadsheet apps or versions include doing fancy calculations inside a pivot table, so here's a way to accomplish this using just simple tools:

[image]

I added a helper column to identify all of the companies that had people who had been contacted within less than 4 months.  The formula in D2:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,A2,$C$2:$C$13,"<4")
```

This counts every record with the same company name as the current record that also has a months value less than 4.  So only companies with zero counts qualify.

Then a pivot table summarizes the company names after filtering on the helper column to include only values of zero.